# English language does not listed in App Store page

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect

I recently added multi-language support to my app. However, after I released that the English is no longer visible in App Store page's language screen (see last screenshot). Has anyone got the same issue? I work with Xcode 15 and String Catalogs. Any help is appreciated

[image: Localization section under project's Info]

[image: String Catalogs]

[image: App Store page language section]

Comment: I fixed this problem. Here is what I did. I removed stale translations from English localization and I filled out English-en fields with default English translations. I do not know which one worked but now "EN" appears under languages in App Store :)